# Determine floors using barometer on iOS

Tags: ios, swift, sensors

I've been trying to register some air pressure values recorded on each floor in order to later use them to find out on which floor the user is. However, I have noticed that the air pressure values are not consistent, and are often influenced by factors such as weather.

Is there a way to "calibrate" the barometer so I can still compare the current value to the previously recorded ones?

Comment: The imprecision of the barometer is almost certainly far too large to discriminate between floors.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Is there another way to do this? Perhaps using GPS? Although I am not sure how accurate this would be indoors @Alexander

Comment: Barometers are based on air pressure. In a sealed office that can change just due to the AC coming on. Airplanes have to regularly adjust their altimeters due to pressure changes caused by weather. It's just not going to work well to detect what floor you are on.

Comment: Hey thanks for the reply. Is there a way to achieve this without using the barometer then? @rmaddy Cheers!

Comment: @MagicDoctor have you tried any of the altimeter apps in the App Store to see how accurate their readings are? I'm curious if they all make the same determinations.

Comment: @MagicDoctor and yes, you can effectively calibrate the barometer and should because you wouldn't use raw values to guesstimate the floor anyway, you would calculate the difference between two values. So have the user record their elevation on the first floor and set that as base zero, store it in a property, and calculate delta as the reading changes. The accuracy of your guesstimates will be based as much on the barometer reading as your algorithm. With certain buildings, you will nail it and with others you may fail miserably so consistency is your enemy. Best of luck on this project.